# Print all lines between a searched pattern of a text file to different file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file called `test.txt` that contains:

```
....Request....
asaksa
sda
dsad
dsad
....Request...
21mklk
nnm212
mkmr543
849238
....Request...
4392840
kndska
94i0-jkfjdk
smdla
.....Request..
839281
ksndlka
nsc
mcxmzl
```

I want all lines between two "Request" pattern should print to different -2 file like:

file1 :

```
asaksa
sda
dsad
dsad
```

file2:

```
21mklk
nnm212
mkmr543
849238
```

file3:

```
4392840
kndska
94i0-jkfjdk
smdla
```

file4:

```
839281
ksndlka
nsc
mcxmzl
```

like wise

Answer (score 2):

How about just incrementing a file counter each time you encounter the `Request` string?

```
awk '/Request/ {n++; next}; {print > "file"n}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
csplit -f file -z --suppress-matched - '/Request/' '{*}' <<\DATA
....Request....
asaksa
sda
dsad
dsad
....Request...
21mklk
nnm212
mkmr543
849238
....Request...
4392840
kndska
94i0-jkfjdk
smdla
.....Request..
839281
ksndlka
nsc
mcxmzl
DATA
```

You're asking for how to use `csplit`, basically. Its job is to split its input file out into separate files based on context matches.

```
ls 

file00  file01  file02  file03

cat file00

asaksa
sda
dsad
dsad

cat file*

asaksa
sda
dsad
dsad
21mklk
nnm212
mkmr543
849238
4392840
kndska
94i0-jkfjdk
smdla
839281
ksndlka
nsc
mcxmzl
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the built-in variable `NR` for the record number:

```
awk -v RS='\\.+Request\\.+'  '{if (NR==1) next}  {print > "file"NR-1 }' test.txt
```

and doesn't create an empty file for `file1`.

This slightly longer one removes the empty line at the start and end of each output file:

```
awk -v RS='\\.+Request\\.+' -v ORS= '{if (NR==1) next}  { gsub("^\n",""); print > "file"NR-1 }' test.txt
```